# Finitely presented finite subgroups of a finitely presented infinite group in GAP?

Tags: gap, coxeter-groups

I am trying to work with infinite Coxeter groups in GAP. An example of such a group would be $\langle a, b, c | a^2, b^2, c^2, (ab)^4, (ac)^2, (bc)^4\rangle$ which can be used to describe the 2D (Euclidean) square lattice. The group is infinite but the subgroups generated by any pair of generators are finite. These subgroups then have a straightforward finite presentation inherited from the presentation of the full group, e.g. $\langle a, b | a^2, b^2, (ab)^4\rangle$ (this is just $D_8$).

I can define the first group in GAP as

```
F := FreeGroup(3);
G := F / [F.1^2, F.2^2, F.3^2, (F.1*F.2)^4, (F.1*F.3)^2, (F.2*F.3)^4];
```

and the subgroup generated by the first two generators as

`H := Subgroup(G,[G.1,G.2]);`

but this returns

`Group([ f1, f2 ])`

so GAP does not seem to store $H$ as a finitely presented group. Whenever I ask GAP to do anything with $H$ (find the size, return a specific coset etc) GAP attempts to do this by (as far as I can tell) trying to compute the full coset table for $G$ with $H$ as a subgroup, which unsurprisingly fails because there are infinitely many cosets of $H$ in $G$. There is a section in the GAP documentation titled "New Presentations and Presentations for Subgroups" which suggests using the `IsomorphismFpGroup` function to solve this problem, but this also seems to fail when $G$ is infinite because

`iso := IsomorphismFpGroup(H);`

returns

`Error, the coset enumeration has defined more than 4096000 cosets`.

If I instead just independently define these subgroups as finitely presented groups with the relevant generators and relations then GAP handles all the size calculations etc perfectly well, but I can no longer calculate cosets of these groups using the other elements of $G$ (which I ultimately want to do).

Is there a better way to work with subgroups of this type, or is this just not something GAP is designed to do?

Comment: Coxeter groups are really special; is it true that you'll always want to work with parabolic subgroups (i.e., subgroups generated by a subset of the standard Coxeter generators)?  I wonder if Sage might be better suited?  https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/categories/sage/categories/coxeter_groups.html

Comment: @JBL Yes, I only need these subgroups and cosets of these subgroups. I am actually using Sage already, but as I understand it the group theory functions in Sage are essentially just wrappers which call the equivalent functions in GAP. I think the resolution to my problem is to do as I described in my comment to ahulpke below; essentially impose periodic boundary conditions on the manifold described by the group and so make the group finite. There is a method to do this for hyperbolic manifolds described in section 3.1.5 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.01520

Comment: Ok.  You might also try explicitly constructing your group using a Coxeter group constructor, to take advantage of all the special machinery that exists (both in the world and implemented in GAP/Sage) for them.

Comment: It seems like the Coxeter group classes in Sage/GAP do not allow for creation of general Coxeter groups via a presentation and instead you have to give the name of the group to the `CoxeterGroup()` function and hope that the group you want is implemented. As far as I can tell, infinite hyperbolic Coxeter groups are not.

Comment: I'm not expert in this (I only occasionally work with Coxeter groups that are not finite or affine) so I'm sorry if I'm wasting your time, but I think you should be able to input an arbitrary Coxeter matrix.  For example, when I evaluate CoxeterGroup([[1,3,3,3],[3,1,3,3],[3,3,1,3],[3,3,3,1]]) on Sage it happily tells me that I have given it a rank-4 Coxeter group, and lets me manipulate the group and its elements in various ways.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a machanism to deal easily with this particular situation. Part of the reason is that in general the relators in a subset of generators do not yield a presentation for the subgroup generated by these elements (e.g. consider $\langle a,b\rangle\le \langle a,b,c\mid a=c,b=c\rangle$).

What you can do in your example is to force element normal form:

```
SetReducedMultiplication(G);
```

Then operations which are element based will succeed, e.g. `Elements(H);`, and one could probably get eleemnt lists for cosets.

What would you ultimately like to compute from $H$?

Comment: Interestingly, `Elements(H);` works for this example even without `SetReducedMultiplication(G);`, and `Size(H);` then also succeeds as long as it is called after `Elements(H);`. Unfortunately this does not seem to work in general and fails when taking subgroups of e.g. the Coxeter group describing the order-5 tesseractic honeycomb. 

I am ultimately trying to embed a certain graph onto part of a hyperbolic tessellation and Coxeter groups seem to be the most natural tool to accomplish this.

Comment: In theory I could add extra relations to the presentation of `G` to impose periodic boundary conditions on the tessellation and make `G` finite as well as `H`. The problem is that, becuase the manifolds I want to work with are hyperbolic, I would need to keep adding new relations to the presentation as I enlarge the manifold because the genus of the manifold will also be growing, and I am not sure how to identify what these relations should be.